# Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment after migration of androidX

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, androidx

After migrating androidX getting this error

```xml
   <fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class fragment
>   Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a [`SupportMapFragment`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment) [migrated](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019) from Android Support Libraries to AndroidX Libraries.

In you case use this version or later.

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0
```

If you check the doc it extends `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.